# Hadoop Data node IP isn't a real VM

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm currently running a hadoop setup with a Namenode(master-node - `10.0.1.86`) and a Datanode(node1 - `10.0.1.85`) using two centOS VM's. 
When I run a hive query that starts a mapReduce job, I get the following error:

> "Application application_1515705541639_0001 failed 2 times due to
>   Error launching appattempt_1515705541639_0001_000002.  Got exception:
>   java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No Route to Host from
>   localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1 to 10.0.2.62:48955 failed on socket
>   timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host;
>   For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost"

Where on earth is this IP of `10.0.2.62` coming from? [Here is an example of what I am seeing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z01Dp.jpg)

This IP does not exist on my network. You can not reach it through ping of telnet.

I have gone through all my config files on both master-node and node1 and I cannot find where it is picking up this IP. I've stopped/started both hdfs and yarn and rebooted both the VM's. Both /etc/host files are how they should be. Any general direction on where to look next would be appreciated, I am stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't have any luck on discovering where this rogue IP was coming from. I ended up assigning the VM the IP address that the node-master was looking for. Sure enough all works fine.